# Player movement with voice input (transform.Translate) not working as intented

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have successfully created my first game in Unity which let's user move through surface. It worked fine. However, I now also want to be able to move player with voice input. They player jumps when it hears the word `jump` but for example to move the player forward when it hears `go`, I simply used `transform.Translate(2, 0, 0)`. This moves player in forward direction but it doesn't care how the the surface is, for e.g. it moves through objects or moves straight even if there is a slope ahead. Movement with keyboard doesn't have any of this problem.

This is my code:

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

        
        public CharacterController2D controller;
        public Animator animator;

        public float runSpeed = 40f;

        float horizontalMove = 0f;

        bool jump = false;

        bool crouch = false;

        private KeywordRecognizer keywordRecognizer;

        private Dictionary<string, Action> actions = new Dictionary<string, Action>();


        void Start()
        {
            actions.Add("Go", Go);
            actions.Add("up", Up);
            actions.Add("back", Back);

            keywordRecognizer = new KeywordRecognizer(actions.Keys.ToArray());
            keywordRecognizer.OnPhraseRecognized += RecognizedSpeech;
            keywordRecognizer.Start();

        }


        private void RecognizedSpeech(PhraseRecognizedEventArgs speech)
        {
            Debug.Log(speech.text);
            actions[speech.text].Invoke();

        }



    // Update is called once per frame

    void Update () {

            horizontalMove =  Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

            animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontalMove));

            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) {
                jump = true;
                animator.SetBool("IsJumping",true);
            }


            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch")){
                crouch = true;
            } else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch")){
            crouch = false;
            }

                }
          



        public void OnLanding (){
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", false);
        }


        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            // Move our character
            controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.deltaTime, crouch, jump);
            jump = false;

    }


    void Go()
    {
        transform.Translate(2, 0, 0);
    }

    void Back()
    {
        transform.Translate(-2, 0, 0);
    }

    void Up()
    {
        jump = true;
        animator.SetBool("IsJumping", true);
    }

}
```

What do I need to change so that the player actually moves as intended through voice input.

Thank you very much and sorry if it is a basic question!

Comment: The difference is that e.g. in `Go` the `transform.Translate(2, 0, 0);` "teletransports" the object about **2** fix units to the right while `controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.deltaTime, crouch, jump);` moves the object smooth over time with `horizontalMove` units/second

Comment: Ok, but why can't I use `controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.deltaTime, crouch, jump);` inside the `Go` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that e.g. in `Go` the `transform.Translate(2, 0, 0);` "teletransports" the object about **2** fix units to the right while `controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.deltaTime, crouch, jump);` moves the object smooth over time with `horizontalMove` units/second.

Also note that you shouldn't mix movements via `Transform` with `Rigidbody`(/`Rigidbody2D`) .. this breaks the physics.

You could simply use

```
public void Go
{
    controller.Move(runSpeed * 2, crouch, jump);
}

public void Back
{
    controller.Move(runSpeed * -2, crouch, jump);
}
```

---

I would, however, use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) that **simulates the button** press for a certain amount of time after a voice command and leave the movement in `FixUpdate` in place like e.g.

```
// How long shall the character move into the direction after voice command?
[SerializeField] private float voicePressDuration = 1f;

private bool isVoiceCommand;
private Coroutine voiceRoutine;

void Update () 
{
    if(!isVoiceCommand) horizontalMove =  Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

    animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontalMove));

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) 
    {
        jump = true;
        animator.SetBool("IsJumping",true);
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
    {
        crouch = true;
    } 
    else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))
    {
        crouch = false;
    }
}

void Go()
{
    if(voiceRoutine != null)
    {
        // evtl interrupt an already running routine
        StopCoroutine(voiceRoutine);
    } 

    voiceRoutine = StartCoroutine(ProcessVoiceMove(runSpeed));
}

void Back()
{
    if(voiceRoutine != null)
    {
        // evtl interrupt an already running routine
        StopCoroutine(voiceRoutine);
    } 

    voiceRoutine = StartCoroutine(ProcessVoiceMove(-runSpeed));
}

private IEnuermator ProcessVoiceMove(float value)
{
    isVoiceCommand = true;
    horizontalMove = value;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(voicePressDuration);

    isVoiceCommand = false;
}
```

This way after saying e.g. `Go` the object will move into the forward direction for one second or whatever you configure in the `voicePressDuration`.

Comment: It's a [`Coroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html) .. on top is a `private Coroutine voiceRoutine;`

Answer (score 1):

Move your player through the CharacterController2D, not Translate because this not allow physics to detect collisions.

Something like this:

```
void Go()
{
   controller.Move(2, crouch, jump);
}

void Back()
{
   controller.Move(-2, crouch, jump);
}
```

Comment: It gives `cannot convert from UnityEngine.Vector3 to float`. The move method looks like this `public void Move(float move, bool crouch, bool jump)`. Is there a way to convert `Vector3.right` to float?

Comment: Where did you get the CharacterController2D? From this repo - https://github.com/prime31/CharacterController2D?

Comment: No, it's not the same repo. I followed some other tutorials

Comment: I changed my answer, check this

Comment: If I do this, player just stays there. It does nothing :(

Comment: Ok, I've deleted Time.deltaTime, check this

Comment: Thanks, with this the player was moving very slightly (difficult to notice) but `controller.Move(2* runSpeed, crouch, jump);` worked